# NativeScript ListView: Mobile 1 column/ Tablet 2 columns

Tags: android, ios, nativescript, nativescript-vue

Is there a way to adapt a ListView (containing individual containers of stuff) from one (1) column on mobile to two (2) columns when viewed on a tablet?

+--------+
| Item 1 |
+--------+
| Item 2 |
+--------+
| Item 3 |
+--------+
| Item 4 |
+--------+

+--------+--------+
| Item 1 | Item 2 |
+--------+--------+
| Item 3 | Item 4 |
+--------+--------+

I've tinkered with updating properties on the ListView and StackLayout, but I haven't had any success.

```
<ScrollView orientation="vertical" class="container">

    <ListView for="item in listOfItems" separatorColor="transparent">
        <v-template>
            <StackLayout>
                <GridLayout columns="150,150" rows="35,25" width="326" height="90" class="listing">
                    <Label :text="item.title" col="0" row="0" />
                </GridLayout>
            </StackLayout>
        </v-template>
    </ListView>

</ScrollView>
```

Unless advised otherwise, I'm using `platformModule.device.deviceType` to detect tablet vs. phone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you could use `platformModule.device.deviceType` to identify whether device is Mobile or Tablet.

Regarding layouts I think you should use RadListView, use Linear layout if it's mobile and grid layout with 2 columns if it's tablet.

[Here](https://github.com/telerik/nativescript-ui-samples/blob/master/listview/app/examples/item-layouts/item-layouts-runtime-page.ts#L20-L26) is how you will change the layouts programatically. It was a sample from TypeScript app but still the code should be exactly same on Vue, in the `@loaded` event of RadListView you could set the right layout based device type.